# SmtpFailedRecipientsException for all e-mails addresses I test

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am using this code to send e-mails:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(_smtpServer, _smtpPort);
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_smtpUser, _smtpPassword);
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.EnableSsl = _smtpSSL;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail, toName));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ccEmail))
            mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccEmail, ccName));
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        if (attachment != null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                fileName = "Adjunto " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss" + ".pdf");
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment, fileName, "application/pdf"));
        }
        smtp.Send(mail);

        return true;
```

the problem us that the recipient is only one, and a mailbox that does exist. however, when smtp.Send method is called, the following exception is thrown:

```
{"No se pueden enviar todos los destinatarios."}
    [System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException]: {"No se pueden enviar todos los destinatarios."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233088
    InnerException: {"El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: User unknown / Usuario desconocido / Usuario desconhecido"}
    Message: "No se pueden enviar todos los destinatarios."
    Source: "System"
    StackTrace: "   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)\r\n   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n   en Common.MailHelper.Send(String toEmail, String toName, String ccEmail, String ccName, String subject, String body, MemoryStream attachment, String fileName) en c:\\WorkingFolder\\Proyectos\\Evcom\\Asistencia\\Nueva Normativa\\Asistencia\\Common\\MailHelper.cs:línea 55\r\n   en Common.Ticket.Send(MailHelper mailHelper, MemoryStream pdfStream, String toEmail, String ccEmail) en c:\\WorkingFolder\\Proyectos\\Evcom\\Asistencia\\Nueva Normativa\\Asistencia\\Common\\Ticket.cs:línea 203"
    TargetSite: {System.Net.Mail.MailWriter SendMail(System.Net.Mail.MailAddress, System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection, System.String, Boolean, System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException ByRef)}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to relay email through the smtp server and that server doesn't allow you to do so.

If you are sending to an address that the SMTP server expects to receive mail on behalf of (the one that shows up if you do an nslookup on the MX record for the domain you are sending to), then it should usually work.  However, some mail servers will not accept the message if the mailbox does not exist.  I believe this is what your server is telling you in this case.  Others will accept it and discard it without erroring, so that if you are a spammer you can't use the error to determine if made-up email addresses are valid.

If you are sending to an address that the SMTP server is not one that it expects, then you are asking it to relay email.  That is usually not allowed by most servers unless you are authenticated and have the appropriate permission.

Comment: That server is mine and I use to send e-mails through it by mean of a compact framework application. In that case, i use other smtp server account to send e-mails. I will try the same SMTP parameters I used with the other application.